# Example on using AFNetworking to post XML?

Tags: ios, http, afnetworking

As a followup to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749904/posting-a-serialized-object-with-afnetworking-failing), I cannot get this to work so I need to take a step back I think.

Can someone post some sample code on how to post XML to a rest service WITHOUT using params?  Is it even possible?  Basically I have an object with several properties, and I convert this to XML and then need to upload it.  But it fails if there is an image converted to string in the XML.  Without that it works fine.

Even a JSON example would be helpful...

Totally blocked here :P

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSMutableURLRequest -setHTTPBody:`, and set the `Content-Type` HTTP header to `application/xml`.

If you're doing this consistently, you may want to consider subclassing `AFHTTPClient` to add an XML parameter serialization option.